# How to exclude test classes that don't have "Test" in the class name using Eclipse "Run As: TestNG Test"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng, filtering

ENV: Eclipse 2023-06 (4.28.0), Maven 3.9.1, TestNG 7.5.1, Java 8.

Doing development I often use the Eclipse "Run As:TestNG Test" on a selected directory of test files. Following the Maven SureFire plugin convention, all of my test class names are of the form ".*Test", except for integration tests, which follow the FailSafe plugin convention ".*IT".  When selecting a directory of tests that include both SureFire and FailSafe test classes.  I have not been successful in getting "Run As:TestNG Test" to ignore the FailSafe ".*IT" classes, it runs them no matter what I do.

(Excluding classes not a problem when running the tests directly from Maven command line. But it is awkward / difficult to quickly select a single directory of tests from the Maven command line!).

I have tried labeling the FailSafe test methods using TestNG groups, e.g. (@Test(groups = {"failsafe"})) and then excluding the group using a testng.xml file like the following which was copied from the TestNG documentation:

```
<suite name="ExcludeITFiles">
  <test name="test1">
    <groups>
      <run>
        <exclude name="failsafe"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I have tried using testng.xml file to exclude all methods of classes that have the name ".*IT", like this:

```
<suite name="ExcludeITFiles">
  <test name="test1">
    <classes>
      <class name=".*IT">
        <methods>
          <exclude name=".*"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I have also tried different variations of name using RegEx, e.g., <class name=".*IT.*">.
Apparently, the testng.xml <class name= ...> does not accept RegEx expressions even through the official TestNG documentation https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml, section 5, seems to imply that it does! To wit: "Note: TestNG uses regular expressions,...".

I other words, I haven't been able to find any way to specify exclude or include filtering of tests when using Eclipse "Run As:TestNG Test".

Any help would be appreciated.